# Recovering from software storage error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, hard-drive

I boot my Pi off a large HDD. Every once in a while, the system hangs for a bit and the drive gets unmounted and remounted into a read only state. I can't SSH to the system or do anything to fix what is going on. I have to do a hard reset. How can I force the kernel to automatically remount the system and perform fsck on these errors.

I have a watchdog enabled to reboot the Pi after a hang, but that is destructive. Instead, I want to attempt to mount the drive again, safely close it and reboot. Also, let me mention that I don't think the kernel has crashed by then. If I'm SSHing to the Pi already, I'm still logged in but I can't perform anything because it can't even find the reboot function. I can still plug in a keyboard and try commands, but get the error that the command wasn't found.

By the way, does anyone know why this problem occurs?

I wan't to make my Pi have a 100% uptime in the way that if it crashes, it will reboot automatically and fix it's errors. I don't think I have any more watchdogs available so that isn't an option. In the case that this error occurs, how do I SSH into the Pi and run the reboot command? Is there a way to trigger it within the Kernel?

Comment: Maybe it is doing some `fsck` .... ?

Comment: I doubt it because it occurs when I directly connect LAN from the router and my pi and my laptop AMD pull 60mbits. If anything, the DSP is being overloaded and the hard drive  is becoming unreachable